# Community ♦ flagging freeform closed posts for comment

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, moderator-tools, community-user, automatic-flags

On beta sites, when a post gets closed without comment, Community ♦ flags it for moderator attention.

Apparently, a comment entered through the freeform close reason doesn't count:

[image]

<sup>As you can clearly see, there should be no doubt that a comment already exists on the post</sup>

Could this be fixed? I don't think it's that important -- I just have to decline the flag, however on larger sites this may lead to a lot of extra flags.

Comment: +1, I'm guessing that the system adds the comment *right after* the flag is auto-generated. Switching the order there should probably fix it right up :)