# Does anyone read declination reasons on Community's flags?

Tags: support, flags, moderator-tools, declined-flags, community-user

I have been declining some of flags created by Community, in particular "Closed without comment" when the close reason was a custom one (which is comment enough).

Does anyone inspect such declinations or should we report undesired behaviour here on meta.SE?

Note [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125668/dont-make-moderators-select-a-decline-reason-on-communitys-flags) which requests to *not* ask for decline reason on Community flags. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187715/community-flagging-freeform-closed-posts-for-comment) asks to not flag for missing comments when there already is one.

Comment: As far as I know nobody looks at those, and due to the lack of any guidance on validation of community flags I doubt that there is any useful information in there at the moment. Some mods like me just declare all of them as helpful because it is simply quicker than declining.

Comment: "Does anyone inspect such declinations or should we report undesired behaviour here on meta.SE?" Undesired or wrong behavior by Community always should be reported.

Comment: I wouldn't dare decline Community ♦. It's basically a self-aware machine (i.e. a terminator). No way I'm pissing him/her off.

Comment: [Funny you should ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105813/where-precisely-does-feedback-on-community-generated-flags-go-to-die)

Comment: Declined: I'm a little teapot, short and stout.

Comment: @JonW I've declined 5 out of the latest 14 flags by Community. But this is not a representative figure, Community has had a helpful streak lately. I'm pretty sure I've declined a majority of them overall. If [cs.se]'s Community becomes Skynet, you know who to blame.

Comment: @JonW: And here I was thinking SE could train Community using the feedback. Didn't think this through.